# Ambiguity between Visual SourceSafe and Volume Shadow Service

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I was browsing the [visual-sourcesafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-sourcesafe) tag recently out of curiosity and noticed pretty quickly a couple of questions that were about [volume-shadow-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volume-shadow-service).

Since VSS is a common acronym for both, it’s not surprising that someone would get confused. [vss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vss) is currently setup as a synonym for [visual-sourcesafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-sourcesafe).

I retagged the two questions but I suspect there might be more.

- [how to provide vss backup as it be displayed in previouse version tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917629/how-to-provide-vss-backup-as-it-be-displayed-in-previouse-version-tab)
- [VSS backups cause custom windows service to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981923/vss-backups-cause-custom-windows-service-to-fail)

Two questions:

First, should we (or myself) go through the list of 700 some-odd questions to find and retag any other Volume Shadow Service questions? I worry about bumping up old questions unnecessarily, and of course of being caught in some kind of edit ban.

Second, What about the [VSS] tag synonym itself? Should it remain as-is or become a synonym for [volume-shadow-service]? That’s a bit harder to decide. On the one hand, SourceSafe is an outdated technology and we don’t expect to see much traffic there in the future. We had 13 questions with that tag in 2018. On the other hand, Volume Shadow Service is not typically a programming topic (although it can be) and questions about it are even rarer. In fact, there are ten times more [Visual-SourceSafe] postings total than [volume-shadow-service] ones. I suppose the VSS synonym could also be dropped and blocked as too ambiguous (tags can be blocked right?).

Of course, an argument can be made that these are low volume tags and it’s better to leave it all alone.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have used @1201ProgramAlarms’s suggested search and retagged the Volume Shadow Service questions in that group. Hopefully that’s good enough.

The question of whether something should be done to the [vss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vss) tag remains up in the air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions with incorrect tags should have them fixed.  A quick search for [`[vss] shadow`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvss%5D+shadow) shows about 2 dozen questions, less than half that need the tag changed.

I don't know what to do about the synonym.  Probably just keep it the way it is, since if you look at the description that comes up it is obvious what it means.

Comment: That’s a big “if”, my dear friend. Wasn’t Visual SourceSafe dropped like in 2005? I wonder when we’ll stop getting questions about it.

Comment: I should have thought of that search. Thank you.